# Find positive integers $a, b$ such that $491! = 11^a \cdot 7^b \cdot c $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The question is to find positive integers $a, b$ such that $491! = 11^a \cdot 7^b \cdot c $ where $c$ is a natural that is not divisible by either $11$ or $7$.

Giving it some thought I believe to have reached something tangible, but not too sure on whether or not it suffices:

Of course $491! = (491)(490)...(2)(1)$ so any multiple of 11 which is $<491$ will be here. That is, every $11 \cdot k $ for $k\le 45$ $\space$ (for $11*46>491$). So the exponent of $11$ in the prime decomposition of $491!$ will be at least $45$. But we have to account for the numbers which are divisible by powers of $11$. How to do that? Well, we've already established $k \le45$ so there is only one number with such property: $11^2$. Now we just have to sum $44$ (for the numbers divisible only "one time" by $11$) and $2$. That is $46$.

Now, for the exponent of $7$ the work to be done is analogous.

It might seem a bit trivial to some of you, but it's bugging not to know whether my reasoning is correct. Thank you in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Your method works perfectly. Great job discovering it! You may use [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+491%21) to doublecheck

Comment: You have the right approach but you've slipped on the details.  More than one multiple of $121$ appears in your product.  I think $a=49$.

Comment: @RobertShore:  did you mean $48$?

Comment: cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398690/find-the-exponent-with-which-5-is-among-the-1000)

Comment: You might also want to look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) in Wikipedia.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I didn't, but I should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following the hints given in the comments, since $11\cdot 44=484$, for $491!$ the factor $11$ appears at least $44$ times and we need to add

- one more factor for $11\cdot 44$
- one more factor for $11\cdot 33$
- one more factor for $11\cdot 22$
- one more factor for $11\cdot 11$

therefore the exponent for $11$ is $48$.

Answer (score 2):

Multiples of $11$ are $\{11,22,33,...,484\}$ which are $44$ of them and among them we have multiples of $121$ which are $\{121,242,363,484\}$ which are four of them.

Thus the power of $11$ should be $44+4=48$

With $7$ we have multiples of $7$ as $\{7,14,21,...,490\}$ which are $70$ of them.

Among them we have multiples of $49$ which are $\{ 49,98,...,490\}$ which are $10$ of them.

Among these we have one multiple of $343$ which is $\{343\}$

Thus the power of $7$ is $$70+10+1$$ which is $81$

Answer (score 2):

For $a$, we first count the number of multiples of $11$, which are $\left[\dfrac{491}{11}\right]=44$. However, the multiples of $11^2$ give a more "$11$", so we need to count again: $\left[\dfrac{491}{11^2}\right]=4$. Therefore, $a=44+4=48$.

Similarly, $b=\left[\dfrac{491}{7}\right]+\left[\dfrac{491}{7^2}\right]+\left[\dfrac{491}{7^3}\right]=70+10+1=81$.

Actually, if you want to find the power of a prime $p$ of the prime factorization of $n!$, you can use this summation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \left[\dfrac{n}{p^k}\right]$$